# Как выводить 1 строку из повторяющихся строк в БД?

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть таблица с такой структурой:

```
ID NAME LOGIN PASSWORD POSITION TEACHER CLASS
```

И есть такой запрос на вывод класса учеников:

```
$classes = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `CLASS` FROM `accounts` WHERE `POSITION` = 'Ученик' AND `TEACHER` LIKE '%$login%'");
```

вывожу всё так:

```
<?php while ($class = mysqli_fetch_row($classes)): ?>
<? echo $class[0] ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

то есть вывод тех классов, в строках которых имеется `$login` (Логин учителя), но есть такая проблема, при выводе таких строк, выводятся и повторяющиеся. Как выводить заместо повторяющихся только 1 строку, при этом чтобы сохранялось условие запроса?

Comment: `SELECT ....` => `SELECT DISTINCT ....` ?

Comment: Всё равно выводит с повторяющимися: 
`$classes = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT CLASS FROM accounts WHERE POSITION = 'Ученик' AND TEACHER LIKE '%$login%'");`

Comment: [быть того не может](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: Я сам не знаю почему так

Comment: ну, покажите, что у вас выводится то?

Comment: Есть 2 строки в бд, в столбце `CLASS` у них значения 10А (у обеих строчек), а когда вывожу, выводятся обе строчки: 10A 10A

Comment: А если вы добавите третью строчку в БД с тем же значением, оно покажет 3 строки на выходе? Кстати, проверьте ещё, одинаковые ли там буквы `A`, а то если одна латинская, вторая русская - то это тогда 2 разные записи.

Comment: Буквы одинаковые и да, если добавить 3 строчку, будет выводить 3 строчки, но вот что я заметил, строчки добавляются с помощью формы и я кое-что заметил, если изменить какое-то значение в самой таблице, а потом вернуть обратно, становится всё нормально

Comment: Судя по вашему описанию, проблема не связана с БД. Откройте mysql базу чем нибудь и выполните там свой запрос напрямую `SELECT DISTINCT ....` , и поглядите, что он будет возвращать. Если вернет как надо, то ищите проблему в вашем коде.

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали и кое-что понял, у меня есть столбец `TEACHER` и если они отличаются, то выводятся повторяющиеся

Comment: Что теперь можно сделать?

Comment: Я хоть БД совсем не работаю, пришлось погуглить немного, но набросал вам [небольшой пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a3629/3) , где `DISTINCT` прекрасно и наглядно отрабатывает.